# How do I clear output cache in Pimcore programmatically?

Tags: pimcore

Note that this is not disable output cache which only disable for certain request, as what the [documentation](https://www.pimcore.org/docs/latest/Development_Tools_and_Details/Cache/Full_Page_Cache.html) specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this in Pimcore 4 source code in `pimcore/models/Object/ClassDefinition.php`

```php
// empty output cache
try {
   Cache::clearTag("output");
} catch (\Exception $e) {
} ?>
```

Although I don't really agree on how this works (they did not specify that "output" is a reserved keyword for cache tags).

Answer (score 2):

Pimcore provide a cli script to clear the cache

```
php pimcore/cli/console.php cache:clear
```

You can run the same command programmatically in any of the php file with exec() function

Comment: I wanted to just clear the output cache, I think my solution works better

Answer (score 0):

Please use this command your project root

```
php bin/console cache:clear

php bin/console pimcore:cache:clear
```